# Sharepoint 2013 Navigation Editing results in Sorry Something Went Wrong Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having a problem with my SharePoint 2013 Home Page navigation. Whenever I edit the links I get a `Something Went Wrong Error` which end up forcing me to restore the database. Steps I took:

1. I Click on site settings
2. I click on navigation (Under Look and Feel) Step
3. I scroll down to Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting area and add or edit a link

> Sorry Something Went Wrong

I then keep on getting the above message whenever I try to access SharePoint.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Like, exactly what are you doing, what patching level is your farm at, what error messages do you get in the ULS logs

Comment: Hi Robert it happens when I change links or add new links on my home page menu.

Comment: I have experienced some problems with publishing cache, but it causes an exception just by saving the navigation page settings, no changes made.

Comment: @ndixmbaya, did you got a solution. As I`, facing the same issue